# adb "geo fix" command to real device of Android?

Tags: android, command-line

How do I test the GPS on a real device?

I connect to the emulator, everything is OK.

```
jdev@jdev-K ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
4df10455333395f1        device

jdev@jdev-K ~ $ telnet 4df10455333395f1
telnet: could not resolve 4df10455333395f1/telnet: Name or service not known
```

Which port?

Tell me, and I can not find. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Unfortunately geo fix doesn't work on real devices.

Not out of the box, but that's why I wrote an app for that :) - it's [open source](https://github.com/luv/mockgeofix) and provides exactly the same interface as the emulator (telnet to :5554 and run "geo fix ..." or "geo nmea"): in app store [MockGeoFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=github.luv.mockgeofix&hl=en)

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately geo fix doesn't work on real devices.

Comment: Then please tell me, how do I test the GPS on my device?

Comment: I always used this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation, but thats quite cumbersome.
Theres another possibility called "mock location provider", I never worked with that, but might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmatically. If you look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) at the very bottom, it has a `setTestProviderLocation()`. That may work. I have not used it however.